# C# MySQL Database insert list of components

Tags: c#, mysql

I am writing a function to have insert a list of strings into a MySQL database and C#.

The process of creating the list of Components:

User has to scan multiple barcodes and have them stored in a list.
The goal is to take that list and insert it into a MySQL database on the click of a submit button.

Is the function below the best way to insert a list of strings into MySQL?

```
public static void insert_db(List components, int id, string product)
{
    string sql = "INSERT INTO table (id, Product, Component) VALUES ";
    for(int i = 0; i < components.Count(); i++))
    {
        sql += "(" + id +"," + product + "," + component + ")";
        if(i+1 != components.Count()) // Make sure its not the last value in the list
        {
            sql = sql + ",";
        }
    }
    sqlCommand InsertDataCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConn);
    try
    {
        InsertDataCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException sq)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sq.Message);
    }   
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp + https://stackoverflow.com/a/23186013/648075 + https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join . Your code looks ancient, you should really look at modern code to use the proper ways to do this. It also mixes business logic (data manipulation) with UI code (MessageBox), which is also really bad.